# Remove "Picture in a picture" popup on YouTube

Tags: youtube

Is there any way to remove "Picture in a picture" pop-up on YouTube? It pops up when you hover over the video and it so annoying and useless. I'm looking for anything: settings, Chrome extension, etc. that will remove it.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the [miniplayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRf7s.png)?

Comment: Yes, the miniplayer pop-up.

Comment: Your image does not exist on the desktop mode. You probably mean in a cell phone. If so, maybe [this is](https://www.howtogeek.com/324401/how-to-use-or-disable-picture-in-picture-mode-in-android-oreo/) or maybe [this](https://www.guidingtech.com/enable-disable-picture-in-picture-mode-iphone-ipad/) what you are after. If so, let me know so I can turn it to a proper answer for future readers.

Comment: It is present in desktop mode.

Comment: Sorry I cannot replicate that.